# Running python script that imports other python script with task scheduler

Tags: python, scheduler, windows-task-scheduler

I have python script called scrape.py where I am importing get_data.py. Both files are in the same directory.

When I run it locally, everything is correct. But I want to run it automatically with Windows scheduler, so I created .bat file. If I run this bat file manually, everything is correct as well.

But when I want to run scrape.py with Windows Scheduler, it will fail because it will NOT import that script get_data.py.

Any help? Thanks

Comment: It’s hard to tell without testing it myself, but is the script actually throwing an error when trying to import your other file? If so, it’s possible that you would have to change the Current Working Directory, which is the place that files which are run look for other files they need. Given your description, that’s the only thing I can think of.

Answer (score 0):

You have to CD to the correct directory.

Comment: CD = 'Change Directory' In other words under scheduler, the default directory (most likely) is not where the files are located, and there is no path set so doesn't know where to find the script .